# Route system with custom tag helper MVC CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

**Custom Tag Helper 'Pagination'**

```
[HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = "page-model")]
    public class PageLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory;
        public PageLinkTagHelper(IUrlHelperFactory helperFactory)
        {
            urlHelperFactory = helperFactory;
        }

        [ViewContext]
        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PageModel { get; set; }
        public string PageRoute { get; set; }
        [HtmlAttributeName(DictionaryAttributePrefix = "page-url-")]
        public Dictionary<string, object> PageUrlValues { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public bool PageClassesEnabled { get; set; } = false;
        public string PageClass { get; set; }
        public string PageClassNormal { get; set; }
        public string PageClassSelected { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
            TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");
            for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.RouteUrl(PageRoute, new { page = i });
                PageUrlValues["page"] = i;
                tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.RouteUrl(PageRoute, PageUrlValues);
                if (PageClassesEnabled)
                {
                    tag.AddCssClass(PageClass);
                    tag.AddCssClass(i == PageModel.CurrentPage
                    ? PageClassSelected : PageClassNormal);
                }
                tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());
                result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);
            }
            output.Content.AppendHtml(result.InnerHtml);
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<div page-model="@Model.PagingInfo" page-route="@(Model.IsSysParamCategory ? RouteUrl.Name.SystemListPagination : RouteUrl.Name.CategoryListPagination)" page-classes-enabled="true" page-class="btn mt-2 mb-2" page-class-normal="btn-secondary" page-class-selected="btn-outline-primary" class="btn-group pull-right m-1"></div>
```

**Controller** - routes

```
[Route("Admin/System/[action]/{page:int}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.SystemListPagination)]
[Route("Admin/System/[action]/{page:int}", Name = RouteUrl.Name.CategoryListPagination)]
public ViewResult List(int valueId, bool isSysParamCategory, DeleteCategoryType deletedCategory, SaveCategoryType savedCategory, int page = 1)
{ }
```

**html is generated like this:**
[image]

**Error:**
*InvalidOperationException: The view 'List' was not found. The following locations were searched:
 /Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/List.cshtml
 /Views/Shared/List.cshtml*

**Question and reflection**

I just dont get it :) I'm using this route paths by name: `'Admin/System/List/{page:int}'` or `'Admin/Category/List/{page:int}'` depending on the logical flag but MVC framework is searchich view at `'Shared'` folder. View is located at: `Areas/Admin/Views/CategoryType/List`

Comment: Answers go in the Answer section, not the Question

Answer (score 3):

I spend some time on this error yesterday and now find solution in 5 minutes!

[solution](https://forums.asp.net/t/2131323.aspx?Aps%20net%20MVC%20Core%202%200%200%20And%20Error%20InvalidOperationException%20The%20view%20List%20was%20not%20found%20)

I get this error because word `Page` is Reserved In Asp.net Core 2